# x86 assembly - compare SF and OF flags

Tags: assembly, x86

How to compare the values of SF (sign flag) and OF (overflow flag) flags in the x86 assembly?

After `cmp` instruction, these flags are set, but I need to compare them in order to emulate the `jl` instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two major instructions testing the flags: the [`Jcc`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html) instruction and the [`SETcc`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html) instruction. Looking at both tables will give you a couple of instructions checking these two flags.

An example using the `SETcc` instruction would be:

```
seto al        ; Set byte to 1 if overflow (OF=1)
sets ah        ; Set byte to 1 if sign (SF=1)
```

Now `EAX` will contain the hexadecimal value

```
0101 if both flags have been set
0100 if sign has been set
0001 if overflow has been set
0000 if both flags have been cleared
```

Now you can compare `AL`(overflow) to `AH`(sign) with `cmp al, ah`. The `jl` instruction checks for difference (SF ≠ OF) so a `jne`(no equal/zero) after this `cmp` has the same effect as the original `jl`.

Finally the whole code emulating a `jl` is:

```
seto al
sets ah
cmp al, ah
jne lesser
```

Comment: I noticed that there is a more elegant way to do this with the ``setl`` instruction (Set byte if less (SF≠ OF)).

Comment: If you are prepared to use `SETL`, then why would you want to __S I M U L A T E__ the `jl` instruction?